# Android build failed adding external library

Tags: android, github, build.gradle

I am trying to include a library in my project, according to the instructions on [github](https://github.com/omadahealth/SlidePager) I have include the following in my build.gradle file:

```
compile 'com.github.omadahealth.slidepager: slidepager: 2.2.4@aar'
```

But i get this
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPEPM.png)

**Top-level build file**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Module:app Build file**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.exampleapp"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.github.omadahealth.slidepager:slidepager:2.2.4@aar'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

they use other libraries, they use other libraries dependencies, if u add

```
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.1@aar'
compile 'com.github.orangegangsters:library:1.3.4@aar'
compile 'com.github.omadahealth.slidepager:slidepager:2.2.4@aar'
```

U get one `Error:(91, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'tv_typeface'`.

I sample to download them and add them to the library gradle?

Comment: I include these libraries but I'm getting the same error as you, I do not know what to do.

Comment: @user3144598, copy lib u project and settings gradle, include ':app', ':lib' and build gradle compile project(':lib')